# WebGL framebuffers : gl.clearColor doesn't appear to affect alpha channel within FBO

Tags: html, webgl2

I'm in the middle of trying to port something from OpenGl to WebGL. I'm finding that for some reason, `gl.clearColor(0,0,0,0)` doesn't appear to change the alpha values at all when called from within my framebuffer, as opposed to trying to call that function on the main backbuffer which results in correctly rendering the backbuffer transparent.

I believe I have an RGBA texture set up correctly on the Fbo-

- internal format is RGBA16F
- format is RGBA
- texel is set to FLOAT

(note I remember it's usually also RGBA for the internal format but this throws an error in WebGL2 as an invalid combo with the other settings)

Anyone have any clues as to how to get alpha transparency working in a framebuffer? Any ideas are appreciated.

EDIT: forgot to note that in my OpenGl code I'm not using blending

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you want debugging help **you must create a a minimum verifiable complete example and put it in the question itself**. Right now you're basically saying "I think I'm doing everything right but it doesn't work" now what? My crystal ball is currently out for maintenance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you enable rendering to floating point textures? Without checking for and enabling the `EXT_color_buffer_float` extension you can not render to floating point or half floating point targets.

Otherwise it works for below.

```js
function main() {
  const gl = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("webgl2");
  if (!gl) {
    alert("need WebGL2");
    return;
  }
  const ext = gl.getExtension("EXT_color_buffer_float");
  if (!ext) {
    alert("need EXT_color_buffer_float");
    return;
  }
  const tx = gl.createTexture();
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tx);
  gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA16F, 1, 1, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.FLOAT, null);
  const fb = gl.createFramebuffer();
  gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, fb);
  gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.TEXTURE_2D, tx, 0);

  gl.clearColor(.1, .2, .3, .7);
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  const floatPixel = new Float32Array(4);
  gl.readPixels(0, 0, 1, 1, gl.RGBA, gl.FLOAT, floatPixel);
  console.log("framebuffer:", floatPixel);
  gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null);
  const uint8Pixel = new Uint8Array(4);
  gl.readPixels(0, 0, 1, 1, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, uint8Pixel);
  console.log("canvas:", uint8Pixel);

  // render it
  function createShader(gl, type, src) {
    const sh = gl.createShader(type);
    gl.shaderSource(sh, src);
    gl.compileShader(sh);
    return sh;
  }

  const vs = createShader(gl, gl.VERTEX_SHADER, `#version 300 es
  void main() {
    gl_PointSize = 300.0;
    gl_Position = vec4(0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  `);
  const fs = createShader(gl, gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER, `#version 300 es
  precision mediump float;
  uniform sampler2D tex;
  out vec4 color;
  void main() {
    color = texture(tex, vec2(.5));
  }
  `);

  const prg = gl.createProgram();
  gl.attachShader(prg, vs);
  gl.attachShader(prg, fs);
  gl.linkProgram(prg);
  gl.useProgram(prg);
  gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, 1);
}

main();
```

```css
div { color: red; font-size: xx-large; }
canvas { position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; z-index: 2 };
```

```html
<div>behind</div>
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering Greg! I did have the extension enabled. Besides this oddity, my FBOs otherwise work as expected and alpha can be manipulated, it's just the clearing functions didn't appear to work.

After a bit more tweaking with the shader( I had messed with it a bit to try and correct a separate issue) and turning on blending I managed to get behavior closer to what I was trying for. 

Gonna mark your answer correct though as it might help someone  else. Thanks again!